# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when accessing images

Tags: php, server

My PHP scripts are not loading any images:

```
<img src ="path/to/img"...
```

So I tried to access the images right from url path to debug, using the browser.

This is the path pointing to my images:

```
exemple.com/system/img/1.png
```

I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

BUT, When I access from my smartphone, that is using 3g/4g it works!

What is happening?

Comment: How is PHP loading the image? `File_get_contents`? What if you run `get_headers` on it?

Comment: @chris85, echo '<img src=...'; Also not working when I access from chrome

Comment: What do you get for a response when you run get_headers on the image address?

Comment: Could you provide full paths? This is uncheckable and we can only guess what goes wrong.

Comment: @chris85 i am getting 'DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN' when I run get_headers

Comment: If you swap the server's IP in place of the domain name does it resolve?

Comment: @chris85 our cloud service is provided by another company, I've got an IPV4 I discovered through the domain but when I tried to access it from browser I got 404.

Comment: When I access from my smartphone it work properly, so,  the problem is my network?

Comment: best guess, your phone use a good, frequently updated DNS (like GoogleDNS 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4 ), and your computer use a crappy DNS (like the norwegian Telenor's DNS or the vietnamese Mobifone's DNS, they uses HOURS  to detect what GoogleDNS detects in MINUTES OR SECONDS) - NXDOMAIN is the giveaway